# Time difference in days from a datetime string to current time in Swift 5

Tags: swift, datetime, date-difference, dateformatter

I have a DateTime string as "15/06/2019 02:03:20 PM IST". I need to calculate the time difference in days between the DateTime string and current date & time.

I am able to get currentDateTime using

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz"
let now = Date()
print(dateFormatter.string(from: now))      //It gives output as 06/10/2019 11:08:52 AM GMT+5:30 not as IST timezone.
```

But I am unable to convert the given DateTime String to a date object for getting the differnce.

```
let registrationTime = "15/06/2019 02:03:20 PM IST"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: registrationTime))       //prints nil
```

I tried adding calendar, locale and timezone  to the dateformatter but it didn't return the date object. I also tried breaking the registationTime in components (separated by whiteSpace) and individually convert them to date from string but that also didn't work.

Comment: I assume your second conversion is meant to be `date(from:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work with India Standard Time you need to set your locale to one for India

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")
```

---

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")

let now = Date()
print(dateFormatter.string(from: now))

let registrationTime = "15/06/2019 02:03:20 PM IST"
print(dateFormatter.date(from: registrationTime))
```

> 06/10/2019 09:35:48 AM GMT+2
>   Optional(2019-06-15 08:33:20 +0000)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked and I got the difference of dates now...